# For purchase or for purchasing

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I just realized there's plenty of people use "for purchase" as much as do with "for purchasing"

How each of them can be functioned since they both are nouns?

Comment: What do you mean by "How each of them can be functioned"?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. "[For](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for)" is usually followed by a noun phrase, e.g. "for lunch", "for a rest", "for variety", "a stickler for detail", "point for point".

Comment: See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=available+for+purchase%2Cavailable+for+purchasing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) showing that products are nearly always *available for **purchase***, not ***...purchasing***.  They might also sometimes be [*available **to** purchase*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=available+for+purchase%2Cavailable+to+purchase&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3), but nothing can ever be *available **to purchasing***.

Comment: 'For sale' is far more common than 'for selling' in a straight shoot-out.